# tmap return an error when adding a plot layer over "World" base Map

Tags: r

I am working on geospatial data :

```
 place_name    id region_country     x     y
    <chr>      <dbl> <chr>          <dbl> <dbl>
     1 Barcelona  10102 Spain           41.4  2.18
     2 Bilbao     10103 Spain           43.2 -2.97
     3 Cadiz      10104 Spain           36.5 -6.30
     4 Gibraltar  10106 Spain           36.1 -5.35
     5 La Coruña  10107 Spain           43.4 -8.38
```

I want to plot this cities over the World basemap of tmap.

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)
data("World")
```

Here are my data :

```
x <- c(41.38333, 43.25000, 36.53361, 36.13333, 43.36667)
y <- c(2.18333, -2.96667, -6.29944, -5.35000, -8.38333)
```

Creating a data.frame object :

```
 geocode <- data.frame(x,y)
```

Converting to sf object :

```
geocode2 <- st_as_sf(geocode, coords = c("x", "y"))
```

Building the map :

```
map1 <- tm_shape(World) +  # basemap
        tm_fill() +
        tm_borders() +
        tm_shape(geocode2)+      # dots shape
        tm_dots()

map1
```

The error :

```
Error in if (!tmaptools::is_projected(shp)) { : valeur manquante là où TRUE / FALSE est requis
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I try your code I get a warning rather than an error:

```
> map1
Warning message:
Currect projection of shape geocode2 unknown. Long-lat (WGS84) is assumed.
```

but the reason might be the same:

```
geocode2 <- st_as_sf(geocode, coords = c("x", "y"))
```

creates an object without a coordinate system reference, so `tmap` doesn't know for sure how to convert it the same coordinate system as the World map.

Assuming your coordinates are WGS84 Lat-long coordinates, then specifying the CRS as 4326 thus should work (code 4326 is the EPSG code for the usual WGS84 lat-long system)

```
geocode2 <- st_as_sf(geocode, coords = c("x", "y"),crs=4326)
```

You might also want to do `tm_dots(size=2)` in order to see any dots.

The difference between your error and my warning might be due to the `tmap` version. I am on:

```
> packageVersion("tmap")
[1] ‘2.3.2’
> packageVersion("tmaptools")
[1] ‘2.0.2’
```